# How to set onclick event for the navigation icon in Material Components top app bars (Android)

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

I created a top app bar by using the Material Components(Android), and changed the navigation icon from the menu icon to an arrow icon. The on click event is back to the previous page. I have already read through the official docs and it doesn't work in my case. I have no idea how to set on click event for that arrow icon. Any help is appreciated.

**A better image to understand what I am talking**
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyNuv.png)

**Link of the docs** [Click me](https://material.io/develop/android/components/app-bars-top)

**settingsActivity.java**

```
package studio.itztaylorau.dashboard;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

import studio.itztaylorau.dashboard.R;
import studio.itztaylorau.dashboard.AccountActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        View topAppBar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
        topAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
}
```

**settingsActivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="@string/topAppBarTitle_Settings"
                android:background="@color/appTopBar"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a fragment transaction on the `settings` `FrameLayout` placeholder, but this placeholder also contains the `AppBarLayout` of the toolbar.

**To solve this:**

**Step 1:** Get the `AppBarLayout` out of the Fragment `FrameLayout` placeholder, So, change the layout to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/appTopBar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
            app:title="@string/topAppBarTitle_Settings" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2:** Instead of `topAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener`, use `topAppBar.setOnClickListener`

```
View topAppBar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
topAppBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my code and it works.